# Script for changing folders name doesnt work

Tags: bash, shell, awk, console

I am trying to change all folders names to lowercases from uppercase. Unfortunately I cant make it happen.I know how to change folders names but my pipes and script don't work.

I made this script to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *;
do mv "$i" echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
done
```

I know that when I do `mv "$i" "Z$i"` it would put `Z` in front of the others folders name.

Comment: You need backticks around the code that changes the case.

Comment: backticks? can u show example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
mv "$i" echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}'
```

Try:

```
mv "$i" `echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}'`
```

or

```
mv "$i" $(echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
```

Comment: You should not use old and outdated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `mv "$i" $(echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}')`.  You can also use here document to get data into `awk` from variable like this: `mv "$i" $(awk '{print tolower($0)}' <<< $i)`

Answer (score 1):

Use some command substitution techniques

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *;
do 
mv "$i" $(echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *;
do 
mv "$i" `echo $i | awk '{print tolower($0)}'`
done
```

you can also use translate, `tr` to perform the same function.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *;
do 
mv "$i" `echo $i | tr A-Z a-z'`
done
```

the `tr` translate each element in first list with corresponding element in the second list.

Answer (score 1):

I think using any external utility for this a little bit overkill. In newer [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can use something like this:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i,,?}"; done
```

I also would suggest to use `-i` option for asking interactively to move if the target file exists.